# Why I can't hide this div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am pretty new in JavaScript and JQuery and I have the following problem.

Into a page I have the following select dropdown:

```
<select id="selTipoRap" class="form-control" th:field="*{tipoRappresentante}" required="required" style="width: 55%;" onChange="nascondiBoxDocumentazione(this);">
    ......................................................................
    ......................................................................
    OPTIONS LIST
    ......................................................................
    ......................................................................
</select>
```

Then I have this JavaScript function that is performed when the usere select an option into the previous select:

```
function nascondiBoxDocumentazione() {
    alert("NASCONDI");

    elementoDaNascondere = $("#docDelega");

    selectedItem = $("#selTipoRap option:selected").text();
    alert(selectedItem);

    if(selectedItem == "Commissario Prefettizio" || selectedItem == "Delegato del presidente di provincia" || selectedItem == "Presidente di provincia" || selectedItem == "Sindaco") {
        elementoDaNascondere.css("display: none;");
    }   

}
```

As you can see this function retrieve the value of the textual value of the selected option (it works fine) and if the text is one of the provided values have to hide a div in the DOM (having **id="docDelega") by this line: **elementoDaNascondere.css("display: none;");**

But it can't work and this div still appear. Using the FireBug debuger I can see that the **elementoDaNascondere** is correctly inizialized and contain the selected div.

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Well you do not show it if it is not a match.... And that is not how you use `css()`. Read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: .css("display", "none")

Comment: try elementoDaNascondere.style.display = "none"

Comment: Since you're using jquery just use elementoDaNascondere.hide(); it's the way you're setting the css. In jquery it's css('property', 'value') it's not the same as setting it in the css file.

Comment: Do you use ´elementopDaNascondere´ elsewhere or declared it elseqhere? If no, put a `var` before it, for a proper declaration of the variable. Otherwise it's going to be a global variable, and that's not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `elementoDaNascondere.css("display: none;");` use `.hide` or  `.css('display', 'none');`

```js
function nascondiBoxDocumentazione() {
    var elementoDaNascondere = $("#docDelega");
    var selectedItem = $("#selTipoRap option:selected").text();

    if (selectedItem == "Commissario Prefettizio" || selectedItem == "Delegato del presidente di provincia" || selectedItem == "Presidente di provincia" || selectedItem == "Sindaco") {
        // elementoDaNascondere.hide();
        elementoDaNascondere.css('display', 'none');
    }   

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selTipoRap" class="form-control" th:field="*{tipoRappresentante}" required="required" style="width: 55%;" onChange="nascondiBoxDocumentazione(this);">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>Commissario Prefettizio</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<div id="docDelega">DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look:

**Change:** elementoDaNascondere.css("display: none;");

**To:** $(elementoDaNascondere).css("display", "none");

Others:

**1.** $(elementoDaNascondere).hide();

**2.** $(elementoDaNascondere).attr("style", "display:none");

**3.** $(elementoDaNascondere).css("visibility", "hidden");

```js
function nascondiBoxDocumentazione() {
  $("#divTest").css("display", "none");
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" onclick="nascondiBoxDocumentazione()" value="Teste"/><br><br>
<div id="divTest"/>
```

Comment: The selector is already assigned to elementoDaNascondere. So you don't need the `$()`.

Comment: @Rafael Right, i use for maintenance of default code

Answer (score 1):

Try to use .val() method. It will get value of selected option and you can add ckech by value (it is more usefull).

```
elementoDaNascondere = $("#docDelega");
selectedItem = $("#selTipoRap option:selected").val();
if(selectedItem == 2){ //enter required value
    elementoDaNascondere.hide(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try elementoDaNascondere.hide(); instead to hide ur div
Are you sure it enters condition and returns true.
for that try putting alert or console.log('something').

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `.css()` correctly.

You have two ways of using it.

1. One of them is when you want to add/change just one property:

   ```
   $("#foo").css("property", "value");
   ```

   There you pass two string arguments, the first containing the css property to be added/changed and the second is the value you want it to have.
2. The second is when you want to add/change multiple properties. Here you'll pass an object.

   ```
   $("#foo").css({"property1" : "value1", "property2" : "value2"});
   ```

   There I'm passing an object literal, but you can pass "an object inside a variable too"(in quotes because it's not an object inside a variable, the variable is the object).

So the correct use of your `.css()` would be:

```
elementoDaNascondere.css({"display" : "none"});
```

or

```
elementoDaNascondere.css("display", "none");
```

And you could also use `.hide()`, wich I prefer:

```
elementoDaNascondere.hide();
```

---

And one more observation:

Have you declared this variable before assign value to it??:

> ```
> elementoDaNascondere = $("#docDelega");
> ```

If not, this variable will become a global variable and, normally, globals are to be used just in some really specific things. Always try to find some other way out to get the values of variables outside the function (both ways).

Do this:

```
var elementoDaNascondere = $("#docDelega");
```

Always pay attention in the scope of your variables.